# what's the sentence meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I read this sentence in the twilight's book but I don't get it:
"But I knew myself too well too think I would really have the guts to do it.
***I made the Cowardly Lion look like the Terminator***"
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I make *this* look like *that*. 
>   In comparison to me, *this* seems the same as *that*.

The two statements above carry the same general semantics.

The Cowardly Lion is a character from the novel *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*.  The Terminator is the eponymous character from the film *The Terminator*.

> In comparison to me, one of the least brave figures in children's literature seems as brave as a fearless robot soldier.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what a twilight's book may be, but it doesn't seem to be written in competent English. The references in the bolded sentence are references to characters in movies that are well known in the US. The Cowardly Lion is a symbol of utter cowardice. The Terminotor is a symbol of utter fearlessness.